# How to cast into a custom @Type (PersistentDateTime) in Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql, jodatime

I have mapped the `statusDate` field to `org.joda.time.DateTime` in the `Foo` class as follows:

```java
@Column(name = "STATUSDATE", nullable = false)
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime statusDate = null;
```

I append the following subselect in the query (the where clause is really simplified for the sake of this question) and the value is sent through the constructor into an existing constructor matching `org.joda.time.DateTime` for such a field:

```
sb.append(", (select foo.statusDate from Foo foo where foo.id = :p_fooId) as fooStatusDate");
```

So far so good. However, there is a case I have a condition where I need to select `null` as the correct type instead.

```
sb.append(", (cast null as <customType>) as fooStatusDate");
```

This does not work as I cannot find how to cast correctly so the `CustomType` would be matched. My attempts and their results:

1. These result in an inappropriate constructor error. Though I can create a constructor to handle this type and parse if not null, I prefer correct casting:

   - `cast (null as string)` results in Hibernate's `StringType`.
   - `cast (null as timestamp)` results in Hibernate's `TimestampType`.
   - `cast (null as date)` results in Hibernate's `DateType`.

   > ```
   > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
   > Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class
   > ```
2. These result in `null` and then fail on NPE as the type is not recognized:

   - `cast (null as localdate)` results in `null`.
   - `cast (null as persistentdatetime)` results in `null`.

   > ```
   > java.lang.NullPointerException
   >  at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.getConstructor(ReflectHelper.java:355)
   >  at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.resolveConstructor(ConstructorNode.java:180)
   > ```
3. Finally, this one doesn't even result in a parseable query:

   - `cast (null as org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime)` isn't even parsed.

   > ```
   > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
   > expecting CLOSE, found '.' near line 1, column 180
   > ```

---

How to achieve a `CustomType` defined by `PersistentLocalDate`? I must use Spring 4.1.7, Hibernate 4.2.5, and Java 7 on this project. Though I am stuck with the mentioned versions, all answers for newer versions are welcome as well! (I upvote these, but do not mark them as accepted.)

The screenshot is from debug breakpoint of the `CustomType` I need at `ReflectHelper`,
method `public static Constructor getConstructor(Class clazz, Type[] types)`:

[image]

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran Thanks for the edit, though I really meant Hibernate types, not Java types.

Comment: NP. I'm not an expert to speak but I found this answer which you can check. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3376732/7218656